# node: how to access json key that is a filename with dot

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, require

I have a myjson.json that looks like this

```
{
  "main.css": "main-4zgjrhtr.css",
  "main.js": "main-76gfhdgsj.js"
  "normalkey" : "somevalue"
}
```

The usecase is that I map revision builds to an original filename.
Now I want to access the key in javascript.  If I do this:

```
var myjson = require('./myjson.json')
```

require is so fancy that it sees the '.json' and parses the json for me into an object so

```
console.log(myjson.normalkey)
```

returns 'somevalue'. However

```
console.log(myjson.main.js)
```

must fail.

**So my question is: How does require work with the dot in the keyname?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(myjson["main.js"]);
```

should work for you.